# Can't find symbol class

Tags: android

I made a new library module within my app project called `xyz`. I want to have there Hello.class under its test.

```
public class Hello {
    public static String hello = "hello";
}
```

In my app module's `build.gradle` I included it as

```
testCompile project(':xyz')
```

When I try to run a JUnit test in my `app` module.

```
@Test
public void shouldBeHello() {
    assertEquals("should show hello", Hello.hello, "hello");
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Error:(19,33) error: cannot find symbol class Hello
```

Has anyone dealt with this problem in the past? Thanks.

Comment: Check if you imported this class.

Comment: Yes it is on top of the testing method. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

As I was doing unit testing in module XYZ, that implied that Hello class was in the same Test folder. So I was trying to make use of the same class in the App module not realizing that in order to work then the Hello class needed to be moved into XYZ's main folder. Also all dependencies which I was using before in XYZ needed to be using `compile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"` instead of `testCompile"org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"`.

App's module still relied on `testCompile project(':xyz')`, and showed no more complaints. :)